# how to convert date format in textual date format?

Tags: php

I have displayed a date in a php page which is in dd-mm-yyyy format like-

```
$bdate = new DateTime($_SESSION['booking_date']);
$date2=$bdate->format('d-m-Y');
echo $date2;
```

whic gives output as "23-04-2013".
but i want this like "23rd April 2013". How can i do this in php?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: `$date->format("jS F Y")`

Answer (score 2):

Check out [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) formatting strings to understand how [DateTime::format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) works.

```
print $bdate->format('jS F Y');
```

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Hahaha, take it easy! :)

Comment: @BenFortune For sure! Changed `d` with `j`, thank you for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$bdate = new DateTime($_SESSION['booking_date']);
$date2=$bdate->format('l jS F Y');
echo $date2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you consider in use Javascript ?

You can use the moment.js

```
[year, month, day, hour, minute, second]
moment([2010, 1, 14, 15, 25, 50]); // February 14th, 3:25:50 PM
```

For example... but you can find all in [www.momentjs.com](http://www.momentjs.com)

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you

```
$date2=$bdate->format('jS F Y');
echo $date2;
```

where

> j - Day of the month without leading zeros
>
> S - English ordinal suffix for the day of the month, 2 characters
>
> F - A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March
>
> Y - A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits